# HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child?

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup, android-viewpager, swipe-gesture

I'm basicly going on this site: http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/

But i'm having this problem:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child "

on this line:

addView(internalWrapper);

Here is myHorizontalScrollView class:

```
public class MyHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

int scrollToViewPos = 0;

public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

void init(Context context) {
    // remove the fading as the HSV looks better without it
    setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
}

public void initViews(final MyHorizontalScrollView me, View[] children, int scrollToViewIdx, SizeCallback sizeCallback) {

    LinearLayout internalWrapper = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    internalWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    internalWrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    addView(internalWrapper); 

    final int w = me.getMeasuredWidth();
    final int h = me.getMeasuredHeight();

    sizeCallback.onGlobalLayout();

    int[] dims = new int[2];
    scrollToViewPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        sizeCallback.getViewSize(i, w, h, dims);
        internalWrapper.addView(children[i], dims[0], dims[1]);
        if (i < scrollToViewIdx) {
            scrollToViewPos += dims[0];
        }
    }

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            me.scrollBy(scrollToViewPos, 0);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Allow touch events.      
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Allow touch events.
    return true;
}

public interface SizeCallback {        
    public void onGlobalLayout();
    public void getViewSize(int idx, int w, int h, int[] dims);
}
}
```

MyHorizontalScrollView in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.yahya.LeftSlideMenu.MyHorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="0px"
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:fadingEdgeLength="0px"
android:padding="0px"
android:scrollbars="none" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0px"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0px" >
</LinearLayout>

</com.yahya.LeftSlideMenu.MyHorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `addView(internalWrapper);` that's why is not visible.

Comment: I did actually... At first, i added this line but then compiler gives me this error: " E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child "

Comment: It compiles fine for me like that: [link](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/4RhBDrDbyI8QJTwWlmLI/)

Comment: But I am not sure if I understand what are you trying to do. First you add childrens to internalWrapper and then you remove them and add them again?

Comment: well... at first i was setting them invisible, and then making them visible and adding... then i changed my mind, that's why they are still there, but i do not think that's the problem, is it?

Comment: You were right. I worked fine! But it didn't at that time, maybe that was about cleaning or something i don't know... But still does the same thing... I want it to be like viewPager? isn't that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I was never working with ViewPager. If it helps somehow you can find ViewPager also in compatibility api. [Compatibility API](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)
If you want to implement it you can maybe check Google's source code. [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java)

Comment: Could you please check my updated question? I tried to simplify it, but now it gives me " Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child " this error on line " addView(internalWrapper); "

Comment: Do you have MyHorizontalScrollView somewhere in your xml layout file?

Comment: I do. Updated my question with it.

Comment: OK, just as I tought :) You already have LinearLayout as a child in MyHorizontalScrollView. But because HorizontalScrollView can only have one children you get an exception when adding internalWrapper. You should remove LinearLayout (id="top") from xml or set internalWrapper from xml (findViewById(R.id.top)).

Comment: I'm trying to do same, but when i run my code, it's empty, i embedded the MyHorizontalScrollView to my main.xml with no children. How do i add views to it?

Comment: Add them to LinearLayout. You have more solutions for that. You need to get LinearLayout from xml (findViewById) and call addView method on it.